# Remove duplicate enteries/items from XML in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm getting duplicate results from an XML file. I want to delete the excess ones but am having trouble achieving this using `splice` and `indexOf`. Can someone point me in the right direction??

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("data.xml");

xmlLoader.load(xmlReq); 

var background:bkg;  var textvar:TextField = new TextField;         
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, convertdata);

function convertdata(event:Event){  
    var xmlinfo:XML = new XML(event.target.data);   
    //trace(xmlinfo);


    var list:XMLList = xmlinfo.profile.photography;

    var totalimage:Number = list.length();

    trace("length " + totalimage);

    enterbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, entersite);

    function entersite(event:MouseEvent){
        for (var i:int =0; i<totalimage; i++){
            trace(xmlinfo.profile.photography[i]);

            background = new bkg();
            background.y = i*40;
            background.x =80;
            addChild(background);

            textvar = new TextField();
            textvar.text = list[i];    
            background.addChild(textvar);
        }

    }   
}
```

XML File

```
        <profile>
            <first_name>ann</first_name>
            <last_name> lee</last_name>
            <photography>sport</photography>
            <photography>landscape</photography>
            <photography>still life</photography>           
            <image>img1.jpg</image>

        </profile>

        <profile>   
            <first_name>john</first_name>
            <last_name> thomas</last_name>
            <photography>wildlife</photography>
            <photography>landscape</photography>
            <image>img2.jpg</image>
        </profile>
```

Comment: How do you determine if it's a duplicate?  where is your splice and indexOf code?   At any rate, you use the `delete` keyword, not splice.  Show your relevant code and I can give you a full example/answer

Comment: thats just two examples of the XML file. The code returns 9 values some of which are duplicates.

Comment: Hey LDMS I just got around to getting your code working for me. I do have one problem in a TypeError: Error #1006: for the line                                 var totalimage:Number = list.length();        what does list.length now become? I have tried various solutions but have come up short.

Comment: Just take off the parenthesis.   `list.length`

Comment: OMG of course. Was a bit late when I was attempting that. Thanks a million for your help. So appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do what you'd like:

**Using this test XML**:

```
var xml:XML =   <data>
                <profile>
                    <first_name>ann</first_name>
                    <last_name> lee</last_name>
                    <photography>sport</photography>
                    <photography>landscape</photography>
                    <photography>still life</photography>           
                    <image>img1.jpg</image>
                </profile>;
                <profile>   
                    <first_name>john</first_name>
                    <last_name> thomas</last_name>
                    <photography>wildlife</photography>
                    <photography>landscape</photography>
                    <image>img2.jpg</image>
                </profile></data>;
```

---

```
//create an array, and popluate it with your xml nodes
var list:Array = new Array();
xml.profile.photography.(list.push(toString())); 
// ^ this converts your xmlList to array by running the method in brackets on each item in the xmlList

//sort it so duplicate values are grouped together
list.sort();

trace(list); //this traces out your full list

//now iterate that array/vector
var i:int = 0;
while(i < list.length) {

    //while the next item matches the current, splice it out
    while(i < list.length+1 && list[i] == list[i+1]) {
        list.splice(i, 1);
    }
    i++;
}

trace(list); //this will be your list with no duplicates
```